# Подключение нескольких JS файлов

Tags: javascript

Как правильно подключить несколько JS файлов одной функцией?
Что-то типа

```
addScripts([
   'jquery.js',
   'bootsrtap.js',
   // Прочее
]);
```

Просто на обычном PHP написать функцию и в цикле пройтись по массиву и через require_once подключить все файлы.

Слышал о Require.js, но там какие то колбэки прописывать надо после каждого подключения. Кто какой подход использует

Answer (score 1):

Подключение некритичных скриптов уже на клиенте:

```
function includeJS(srcArray, onLoaded) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        scriptsHave=document.querySelector('script'),
        isLoaded = [],
        callbackCalledOnce = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < scriptsHave.length; i++)
    {
        /*защита от дурака - убираем адреса, если они уже подключены*/
        var found=srcArray.indexOf(scriptsHave[i].src);
        if(found!=-1) srcArray.splice(found,1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++)
        isLoaded[i] = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++)
    {
        /*добавляем очередной скрипт в страницу*/
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        scriptElement.setAttribute('src', srcArray[i]);
        head.appendChild(scriptElement);
        scriptElement.onload = function (x) {
            isLoaded[x] = 1;
            /*незагруженных не осталось и callback не вызывался*/
            if (isLoaded.indexOf(0) == -1 && !callbackCalledOnce)
            {
                callbackCalledOnce = true;
                setTimeout(onLoaded, 100);
                /*без задержки - в разных браузерах иногда косячит */
            }
        }(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем это лучше PHP?, кроме того через require_once не нужно делать проверку на уже подключенный файлы, т.к функция сама выдаст исключение если повторно подключается одинаковый файл

Comment: Но подход понятен

Comment: Как-то влияет на время отрисовки страницы, что-то около SEO. Отложенная загрузка позволит сначала отрисовать страницу без ожидания скриптов, и лишь потом дожидаться их догрузки

Answer (score 1):

**RequireJS** всё-таки хорошее решение именно для вашей задачи. [Скачайте](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) себе сам [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.20/minified/require.js), в теле страницы единственный тег:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

А в скрипте загрузки `scripts/main.js` что-то типа:

```
requirejs([
    "ololo", // .js тут не пишем
    "alala", // скрипты в той же папке scripts/    
], function() {
    // это запустится после того, как все зависимости точно загружены
    function_iz_ololo_js();
});
```

**Другой подход.** Если все скрипты грузятся с вашего сервера, можно собрать их в один файл и минифицировать. Понадобится, скорее всего, [node.js](https://nodejs.org) и напр. модуль [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

Редактировать скрипты будете по-отдельности, а потом запускать команду или маленький деплой скрипт, который их соберёт и сожмёт в *единственный* js файл, который и грузится обычным образом из странице. Можно даже сделать так, чтобы скрипт «следил» за папкой, где вы редактируете код, и автоматом собирал все после каждого сохранения.

Comment: Скажите, а когда происходит document.ready. Когда Dom построен? Сразу вопрос Dom построен когда все скрипты и css подгрузились, или Dom может быт построен и до этого. При условии что все скрипты подгружаются синхронно

Comment: [`.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) – событие от jQuery, его нет в «чистом» javascript. Происходит когда и весь html страницы загружен и спарсен, *и все зависимости* – стили, картинки. **DOM** строится до этого – не дожидаясь картинок, стилей и скриптов. См. событие [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) – оно происходит, когда только html загрузился и распарсился, но не внешние зависимости.

Answer (score 1):

Нафиг сложности , вы говорите что проще через php , но вы забываете что все это хозяйство , при загрузке будет выполнять отдельные http запросы и соответственно тормозить загрузку странички . По мне так чем меньше сделает php тем лучше - его задача нагенерить контент , со всем остальным прекрасно справляется клиент , тем более что сейчас даже телефоны по мощностям как маленькие серваки .

А по поводу подключения js в нужный момент то чем не вариант JQ ?

```
$.when(
    $.getScript("/common/js/WelcomeMatch.js"),
    $.getScript("/common/js/underscore-min.js")
)
.done(function() {
    WelcomeMatch.run();
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("При загрузке одного из компонентов произошла ошибка.");
});
```

Comment: В вашем примере, колбэк done произойдет когда скрипт загрузиться или выполниться?

Comment: Скрипты выполнятся в тот же момент как будут загружены.

Comment: Да все верно , это всего лиш пример того как можно загрузить скрипты и выполнить их только после того как все объекты будут аккуратно загружены . Событие которое может инициализировать этот процесс может быть любым , предположим пользователь подвел мышку к диву где есть кнопка , после загрузки скриптов кнопка станет активной . Разве это не экономия ресурсов , подгружать только тогда - когда есть надобность .

Answer (score 0):

Както так

```
function addScript(scripts) {
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '/path/to/scripts/' + scripts[i];
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
addScript([
    'ololo.js',
    'alala.js',
]);
```

Comment: а как выполнить функцию, которая в ololo.js?
`addScript(['ololo.js']); ololoFunc();` вызовет `ololoFunc();` когда `ololo.js` еще не загрузился

Comment: А кто нибудь использует Require.js.

Answer (score 0):

Как угодно, можно или пользоваться специальными инструментами на клиенте типа Require.js, который умеет подтягивать зависимости при настройке и использовать групповое включение(именно поэтому его используют). Либо создать файл со списком нужных скриптов и подключить его один раз через require_once. Либо, при наличии разных скриптов на разных страниц создать специальный класс PHP, который сгенерирует прямо в разметку нужный код HTML.

А вот велосипеды с document.createElement('script') выложенные к вопросу мне совсем не нравятся, так как смысла в них нет. С таким же успехом можно просто вставить в конец простую HTML разметку с нужными файлами.

Comment: Подход `document.createElement('script')` - призван решить проблему отложенной загрузки, к чему призывает гугловский https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
Просто async+onload не гарантирует выполнения кода, зависящего от нескольких js-файлов